# Continuous Subgraph Matching

Tags: c++, subgraph

Continuous Subgraph Matching is defined as "Given an initial data graph ’, a graph update stream ∆, and a query graph , the continuous subgraph matching problem identifies all positive/negative matches for each update operation in ∆."

Is there an implementation or algorithm for the above problem on insertion and deletion of edges and identify positive/negative matches at the same time?